# v-bind:style with array entry

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm attempting to pass a value within an array to v-bind:style. I've provided an example of my data structure below. Any help will be appreciated.

Sorry in advance for any formatting issues. I rarely ask questions on Stack Overflow to find an answer to my issue, so I don't entirely know how it works.

Entry Data:

```json
["これ", "This", "pronoun"]
```

Vue Template:

```html
<div v-for="entry in translation">
    <p v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: entry[2] }">{{entry[0]}}</p>
</div>
```

Vue Export:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        id: String,
    },
    data() {
        const data = db[this.id]

        return {data, pronoun: "red"}
    },
}
```

It functions perfectly if I just pass "pronoun" to backgroundColor like so:

```html
<p v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: pronoun }">{{entry[0]}}</p>
```

Comment: I don't see where you returned `translation` from your data function. Does your template have access to the `translation` variable?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I've made an edit to the post. `data` holds everything including `translations` (data[id][page][translations][translation][entry])

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<template>
  <p v-bind:style="backgroundColorFunc(2)">Lorem ipsum</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        arrayElem: ["これ", "This", "pronoun"],
      };
    },
    computed: {
      backgroundColorFunc: function(index){
        return {
          backgroundColor: this.arrayElem[index],
        };
      }
    };
  }
</script>
```